# is It possible to make rust recognized the new rust diesel model

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

After I upgrade the diesel_ext to 0.3.10(before upgrade the project build success), show this error when build project:

```
> cargo build
   Compiling cv-server v0.1.0 (/Users/John/source/backend/cv-server)
error: expected identifier
  --> src/model/diesel/cv/cv_models.rs:11:23
   |
11 | #[diesel(table_name = "cv_gen")]
   |                       ^^^^^^^^

error: could not compile `cv-server` due to previous error
```

what should I do to make the rust handle the diesel model file? I have already add the micro annotation in `main.rs` like this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
```

this is the new style model file:

```
// Generated by diesel_ext

#![allow(unused)]
#![allow(clippy::all)]

use rocket::serde::Serialize;
use serde::Deserialize;
use crate::model::diesel::cv::cv_schema::*;

#[derive(Insertable,Queryable,QueryableByName,Debug,Serialize,Deserialize,Default,Clone)]
#[diesel(table_name = "cv_gen")]
pub struct CvGen {
    pub id: i64,
    pub cv_name: String,
    pub remark: String,
    pub created_time: i64,
    pub updated_time: i64,
    pub user_id: i64,
    pub cv_status: i32,
    pub gen_time: Option<i64>,
    pub path: Option<String>,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Diesel 2.0, the `table_name = ...` attribute was changed to take a *path* instead of a string literal. See the [2.0.4 documention](https://docs.rs/diesel/2.0.4/diesel/prelude/derive.Insertable.html#attributes) (compared to the [1.4.8 documentation](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.8/diesel/prelude/trait.Insertable.html#deriving)):

> #### Optional container attributes
>
> `#[diesel(table_name = path::to::table)]`, specifies a path to the table this type is insertable into. The path is relative to the current module. If this attribute is not used, the type name converted to `snake_case` with an added `s` is used as table name

In your case, you probably just want `#[diesel(table_name = cv_gen)]` since it is presumably already imported from `crate::model::diesel::cv::cv_schema`.

---

I don't know what that means for source generated by `diesel_ext`, but it appears Diesel 2.0 is not supported yet. There is [an issue filed](https://github.com/abbychau/diesel_cli_ext/issues/51) and [a PR merged](https://github.com/abbychau/diesel_cli_ext/pull/52) to accommodate this change, but it does not appear there is a [version](https://crates.io/crates/diesel_cli_ext/versions) released that includes it.

Comment: I am using the newest version `0.3.10` seems it not changed, the new version still generate the legacy format. should I compile from the source?

Comment: @spark You can certainly try, but given that its not released, its not clear to me how well Diesel 2.0 is supported. You may still run into issues. The alternative would be to adjust the source manually after being generated.

Comment: thank you, I already do it like that, you saved my time, thank you!